# How can I mock a strongly typed service dependency using PHPUnit?

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I have a service:

```
<?php
class MyService {

    private $dependency;

    function __construct(IDependency $dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }

    public function testableMethod($someArgument)
    {
        $this->dependency->doSomething($someArgument);
    }
}
```

I want to mock `IDependency` in my PHPUnit unit test and verify that the method was called:

```
<?php
class MyServiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function test_testableMethod_callsDependency(){
        $mock = $this->getMock('IDependency');
        $mock->method('doSomething')->willReturn('some stuff');
        $sut = new MyService($mock);

        $sut->isFileDownloadUrl('some argument');

        $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('doSomething')
            ->with($this->equalTo('some argument'));
    }
}
```

This results in:

`ErrorException: Argument 1 passed to FileDownloadService::__construct() must be an instance of IDependency, instance of Mock_IDependency_46fe6bd6 given, called in /yadda//yadda/MyService.php on line 12 and defined`.

Is there any way of dealing with this in PHPUnit?  Or do I need another tool for this?  Or do I have to create my own mock for strongly-typed signatures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is 100 percent possible and I made a booboo elsewhere.  Make sure to get the interfaces right:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('My\Namespace\IDependency');
```